# org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations without using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a spring boot application based on 2.1.0.RELEASE and using hibernate 5.3.7.Final for the most interactions 
to the database, except for couple of cases where i wanted to delete a list of objects and thus i wanted to execute a method that delete that list as a bulk. I can already execute getBulk as a list with a normal hql query, thus
i wanted to to the same for the delete since it is much faster.

the Entities are created like that:

I have a table Attribute that has one to one mapping to a table called Value. 
The value table has only one relation i.e. to the attribute

```
@Repository
@Entity
@Table(name="ATTRIBUTE")
@OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
public class Attribute implements AttributeInterface {

    .......

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="VALUE_ID", nullable=false)
    @OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Value valueId;
}
```

from postgres :

```
\d attribute;
                              Table "public.attribute"
         Column          |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------                           
 id                      | bytea                    |           | not null | 
 .......
 value_id                | bigint                   |           | not null | 
 .......

Indexes:
    "attribute_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    .......
    "fksc44hph1sm89gdg2o01bjiuad" FOREIGN KEY (value_id) REFERENCES value(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

The repository method is annotated explicitly with  @Transactional and  @Modifying annotations. I have the @Transactional annotation in my service class calling delete as well.

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Override
public void delete(Collection<byte[]> list) {


    try {


        Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.flush();
        session.clear();


        String hql_query = "DELETE from Attribute as o WHERE o.id IN (:ids)";
        Query<?> query = session.createQuery(hql_query);

        query.setParameterList("ids", list);
        query.list();



        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

that gives me the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [DELETE from org.Attribute as o WHERE o.id=:ids]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1508)
```

This exact exception is described here and here
    https://www.javabullets.com/spring-data-jpa-query-not-supported-for-dml-operations/

All over the internet i read the i need the

`org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying`

annotation.
I had to add additional dependency i.e. the spring-data-jpa artifacat since i did not had the Modifying annotation. i.e.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Well i do have it now, but is still does not
allow the delete query.

If i change the code a little bit and use hibernate to delete the rows then it all works but this is not a bilk delete in this case and it is slow.
i.e. If i pass the whole attribute as an object and do a for each loop on the collection end call hibernate session directly then it works.

```
    session.delete(attribute);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

My question is what i am doin wrong in the delete bulk method. Is there anything that i am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `Modifying`. `Modifying` is a Spring Data annotation, but you don't seem to use Spring Data.

You are executing [`query.list()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list()) which is used for executing select-statements that return a result.

Since you are trying to execute a delete, you need to use [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#executeUpdate())

For which the JavaDoc states:

> Execute the update or delete statement.